Firefox clear cache and force complete page refresh
Chrome has a similar option for clear the cache and hard reload for a certain page.
For Firefox, I can't clear the cache and hard reload for a certain page

Hold down the shift key while clicking the reload button. It won't clear the cache, but it will make the page behave as if it isn't cached. (Mostly, images loaded by CSS will still be loaded from cache.)

Solution:

Open the developer toolbox (Ctrl+Shift+I or Cmd+Opt+I on Mac).
Click the settings button (near the top right).
Scroll down to the Advanced settings on the bottom right.
Check the option "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)".
Refresh the page.

Don't forget to enable the cache again, if needed
